# SpeechRecognition is not run successfully

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Please help me to solve this. I am using Linux Beta Version with my ChromeOS and
I have a python code here and I don't see any error

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

try:
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration = 0.2)
        audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        text = text.lower()

        print(text)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception "+ str(e))
```

However, it prints like an error message like this

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/perez_brian18/Python Projects/Nexus Voice Assistant Project/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
  File "/home/perez_brian18/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 491, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/home/perez_brian18/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 199, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I try to check and analyze one by one by none of it cannot help me. I suspect that my code must download more appropriately library I guess but I don't know what it is.

Hoping you answer my concern Thank You

I tried installing different libraries and still I cannot solve this error.

Comment: This is related to `jack`, which is a plugin of `ALSA`, the Linux sound subsystem. This isn't to do with Python, but lower-level operating system software. Please run the command `jackd --version` on your system so we can prove `jack` is installed, and post the output here.

Comment: I tried in a terminal and the output is like this version 1.9.17 tmpdir /dev/shm protocol 8

Comment: I think you are running into this bug - https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/issues/722 - can you restart `jackd` and see if that works?

Comment: The result shows copyright and other messages